# ActiveAdmin 1.0.0 belongs_to - Unable to autoload Parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, activeadmin

I'm using the Rails `gem 'activeadmin', '~> 1.0.0.pre2'`, and have so far been able to use it in my project successfully. Several (around 10) objects are able to have CRUD performed on them, some even include foreign keys to other tables. Great stuff!

The issue I've hit is that I have several objects that must be displayed through a `belongs_to` relationship, but when I put a `belongs_to` on the child object within its ActiveAdmin model registration, I get the following error when attempting to run WEBrick locally:

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.4 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:495:in `load_missing_constant': Unable to autoload constant Admin::ParentClass, expected /app/admin/parent_class.rb to define it (LoadError)
```

Here are the model and ActiveAdmin registrations as they exist today:

**app/models/parent_class.rb**

```
class ParentClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sub_objects
end
```

**app/admin/parent_class.rb**

```
ActiveAdmin.register ParentClass do
  permit_params :title
end
```

**app/models/sub_object.rb**

```
class SubObject < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent_class
end
```

**app/admin/sub_object.rb**

```
ActiveAdmin.register SubObject do
  belongs_to :parent_class

  permit_params :name
end
```

With the above setup, I still get the error `Unable to autoload constant Admin::ParentClass, expected /app/admin/parent_class.rb to define it (LoadError)`

...but if I comment out the `belongs_to` in app/admin/sub_object.rb, it works fine (but the route `/admin/parent_classes/{id}/sub_objects` is not defined and does not work)

Why is this, and what do I need to do in order to make this work (with the route I described in the paragraph above)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some help from [Timo](https://github.com/timoschilling) (ActiveAdmin project member) on the Github issue I entered, I was able to figure it out:

```
belongs_to :parent_class, class_name: "::ParentClass"
```

This also seems to be an issue with my particular project, as I wasn't able to reproduce it in a vanilla Rails 4 app with the latest Active Admin 1.0.0 gem pulled in and installed (the `belongs_to` worked without the `class_name` property).

It's not a "standard" rails app as we have a "main" application running an API in the main namespace with an Angular frontend, and then ActiveAdmin in it's own /admin namespace handling a lot of duplicitous CRUD operations for us. But up until now, ActiveAdmin has worked without a hiccup.

If I have the time I will investigate **why** the class_name was needed in my project, but other than make sure it's truly working, I may just not ask and move on.